# Android custom objectAnimator getting display dimensions

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

I'm about a day deep into android, so please correct me if anything is totally unusual, but here is my issue.

I have a frame in which I swap Fragments like so:

```
Fragment f = ... //defined elsewhere
FragmentManager fm1 = getFragmentManager()    
FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm1.beginTransaction();

    ft1.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left,
                            R.animator.slide_out_right);
    ft1.replace(R.id.content_layout, f)
               .addToBackStack(null)
               .commit();
```

and I have two custom animations defined, slide_in_left and slide_out_right, like so (the other is just opposite dimensions):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
  <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:propertyName="x" 
          android:valueType="floatType"
          android:valueFrom="-800"
          android:valueTo="0" 
          android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

This all works fine, and looks pretty good if I manually code the correct values.
What I am unsure is how I am supposed to set the "valueFrom", and "valueTo"  basicaly I need to know the devices width (or frame width) and have it use it there.  I imagine I need to set up some type of callback here, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Many thanks!